# Why is this expression a function instead of a bool?

Tags: types, ocaml

Why is `is_empty kv` considered of type `('a,'b) trie -> bool`, when `kv` is supplied (of what I believe should be type `('k, 'v) -- a Trie)`? After all, the function is defined as recursive, and the other return values are of type `bool`.

As written here, the code snippet is not supposed to be correct, but just works as an example of my confusion about the type system.

in a separate signature file:

```
type ('k, 'v) trie 
val empty : ('k, 'v) trie
val is_empty : ('k, 'v) trie -> bool
```

in the implementation file:

```
type ('k, 'v) trie = Trie of 'v option * (('k * ('k, 'v) trie) list)

let empty = Trie (None, [])

let rec is_empty t = function
|Trie (None, []) -> true
|Trie (Some x, _) -> false
|Trie (None, (k,kv)::tail) -> is_empty kv
```

the error:

```
File "trie.ml", line 11, characters 34-45:
Error: This expression has type ('a, 'b) trie -> bool
   but an expression was expected of type bool
```

Answer (score 2):

The `function` keyword makes one of the arguments implicit, so the `t` argument after `is_empty` is redundant and is the source of the problem.

Thanks to `struk|desk` on `#ocaml` for reminding me about the syntax.

The correct definition of `is_empty` is then

```
let rec is_empty t = function
|Trie (None, []) -> true
|Trie (Some x, _) -> false
|Trie (None, (k,kv)::tail) -> is_empty kv
```